# Member aggregate initializer list unsupported?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
struct bar { int x; };

struct qux
{
    static const int foo[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Error

    static const bar baz = { 0 }; // Error
};
```

Visual Studio 2008; Standard;

```
syntax error : '{'
```

Answer (score 4):

Only integral *static* non-aggregate members can be initialize inside the class.  All other *static* members (aggregate or otherwise) must be initialized outside the class.

```
//tag.h

struct tag
{
    static const int foo[3];  //aggregate
    static const bar baz;    //aggregate
    static const std::string s; //non-aggregate (non-integral type)
    static const int x = 10; //ok : non-aggregate (integral type)
};

//tag.cpp

const int tag::foo[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }; //ok
const bar tag::baz = { 0 }; //ok
const std::string s = "example"; //ok
const int tag::x; //definition - if you want to take its address
```

Comment: No, it's not just silly. The struct definition defines what that type is. It doesn't allocate any space. So somewhere, in a compilation unit, you have to allocate the space for that static data. C++ classes and structs define types of objects. They are not objects themselves.

Comment: That would be valid if this wasn't about members with a static storage class (hint: the whole point)